# How do i predict an exponential trend(covid-19)

Tags: prediction

Hello a newbie to statistics here, I was wondering if there was a statistical way of predicting an exponential trend? I would like to apply it to the number of infected COVID19 patients that is going on in my place.

I know that there are a lot of factors that may affect the spread of the virus but i am hoping to show atleast a general directions to the best medium worst.

What i have is the data number of infected per day for the last 40 days, and i was hoping to see 10 days ahead.

If you could give a formula that would be better since it would be easier for me to code it in

Comment: You could apply the logarithm and then fit a first-order polynomial. If you want formulas, assume that your data is exponential and follows from $ae^{bx}$. If you take the logarithm you have $bx + \log a$, which is a first-order polynomial (a line).

Comment: @OriolB there seems to be a lot of fundamental stuff i do not get there, I apologize. May i know what is this method called so i can read upon it and ask question after?

Comment: I don't know if this method has a name, but there's not much behind it. I put an example as an answer.

Comment: @OriolB Thanks! ill wait for it.

Comment: In this case, I would suggest it is *far* more important to assess the uncertainty in the forecast than it is to make the forecast itself.  Any realistic model of this situation that is as simplistic as an exponential fit will acknowledge such a huge amount of uncertainty that a forecast further out than a day or two will have such a wide prediction interval that it will be obviously useless.  If, instead, you ignore this issue, you will only be creating a fantasy with the illusion of precision, deceiving both yourself and your audience.

Comment: @whuber Aside from the very obvious disclaimer that what i am presenting is only a forecast and maybe totally wrong, the way i present the graph would something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySrXe.png) where it starts out a line and a fan would appear, because you really do see a trend, i can comfortoably draw out a range of where the situation be in a few days. so i assumed the great minds of the statistics world surely have made a formula for such situations.

Comment: There are myriad formulas.  They are only as good as the underlying assumptions.  Their users all understand that those assumptions generally can be checked only for the past data and that it can be foolhardy to assume they will continue into the future.  Thus, honest formulas for prediction intervals tend to produce extremely wide "fans." Ultimately, the width of your fan is going to depend much more on your assumptions--both the ones you explicitly make as well as the ones implicit in the statistical method--than it will on the data themselves.

Comment: For examples of what I'm writing about, see a graphic headed "New York State coronavirus deaths in five different forecasts" at https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/04/22/upshot/coronavirus-models.html?searchResultPosition=2. Bear in mind that these are for a region with tens of millions of people: if yours has smaller numbers and your model is more simplistic than these (it is), your "fan" should be much wider than the spread shown in this graphic--which, less than two weeks in the future, ranges from zero to twice the current value and even *just one day in the future* is nearly useless.

Comment: That article look great, great in terms of information, it even have links to source codes, not so great for me because i have to choose one. Thank you very much for this. Of course i have to make it very clear to my audience as you have said they are only as good as the underlying assumptions

Answer (score 0):

Given your assumption of having an exponential trend, you can apply the logarithm to your data. Doing so, you transform your time series into having a linear trend, which is much easier to model. I provide a simple example in Python below.

In this case your time series is $X_t=f(t)+\epsilon_t$, where $f(t)$ is your trend and $\epsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. You think that your trend is exponential, so this function will have the form $a e^{b (t -c)}$ for some constants $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ that you don't know.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 10)
a = 2
b = 0.5
c = 2
f = lambda t: a * np.exp(b * (t - c))

epsilon_t = np.random.randn(len(time))
X_t = f(t) + epsilon_t

plt.plot(t, X_t, label='Original time series')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

# Compute trend
trend_coeff = np.polyfit(t, np.log(X_t), deg=1)
trend = lambda t: trend_coeff[0] * t + trend_coeff[1] 

plt.plot(t, np.log(X_t), label='Log time series')
plt.plot(t, trend(t), linestyle='dashed', label='Trend')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

And if you are courious, you can note that the theoretical value of the coefficients is $[b, \log a - bc]$, which is relatively close to the [0.529, -0.538] of our fitting considering that our time series is noisy.

Comment: Why is there no trend in the first graph? also since i would like to have High,Middle,Low scenario in my prediction how would i implement that? Middle can be taken care of the trend, but how would calculate the maximum deviation for high and low?

Comment: By adding such a tiny error to the underlying data, you create a nice textbook example but it just won't apply to the actual data, which are going to depart hugely from any exponential trend. Moreover, this definitely is not an appropriate model, because even if the counts were perfectly and accurately known, their variance would still be (at least) proportional to the counts themselves, rather than constant.

Comment: Of course there is a trend in the first graph. I added an exponential trend as you wanted.

Comment: @OriolB oh so you just did not show it, does the trend always have to be linear? its not so obvious in the second graph because the data there is closer to linear than exponential.

Comment: @whuber can you recommend a better model that i can check it out?

Comment: No model that considers only case counts and time is likely to be any good and cannot be trusted for forecasting.  That's why people are using spatio-temporal models of infection and transmission.

Comment: The problem is that the data shows an initially exponential trend, but **at some point, a stabilization will follow and a decrease**. The problem is that the exponential trend, even when it already has a slight tendency to decline in growth rate, does not give *any* information to forecast the point when this will occur. The predictions should be based on auxiliary information, like detailed measurements of the spread, surveys percentage of people that got infected, information about government actions and how well they play out, etc.

Comment: If the system would behave regularly then you could do with a quadratic fit to log-transformed data and project 10 days forward. This works well most of the time. But it doesn't work well to predict when this behavior of regular fairly constant exponential growth will stop.

Comment: The problem with this question is not so much the technical details about how to fit an exponential trend, and it is much more the problem how good this assumption of an exponential trend is and what it means for the prediction interval. The error of an interval is 'variance in the method estimate + bias in the method estimate'.